# Consulta SQL CASE

Tags: sql, xml, oracle-sqldeveloper

a ver si me podéis ayudar con esto:
tengo un xml que sirve para la creación de un grid en una pantalla con varias columnas. Este llaman a un sql para que pueda realizar la función que yo quiera hacer. Los dos campos que quiero hacer son estos:

- Multiholder (Y/N): indica si una entidad legal pertenece a un multiholder (conjunto de entidades legales).
- Nombre multiholder: nombre del multiholder en caso de que pertenezca a un multiholder

Para saber si una entidad legal pertenece a un multiholder hay que consultar la tabla ADM_MULTITITULARES a máxima fecha. El campo maz_cd es la contrapartida y el campo group_alias es el nombre del multiholder.
La tabla tiene los campos: group_alias (VARCHAR2), maz_cd (VARCHAR2), val_date (DATE).

El xml sería algo asi:

```
<column width="25">
   <title>Multiholder (Y/N)</title>
   <properties>
      <VARCHAR field="MULTIHOLDER_INDICATOR"/>
   </properties>
</column> 
<column width="50">
   <title>Nombre multiholder</title>
   <properties>
      <VARCHAR field="MULTIHOLDER_NAME"/>
   </properties>
</column>
```

La segunda columna todavía no la he intentado, pero la primera sí y no consigo resolverlo, yo he hecho esto en sql:

```
SELECT *,
 CASE
  WHEN val_date = (SELECT MAX(val_date)
  FROM ADM_MULTITITULARES THEN 'Y'
  ELSE 'N'
 END AS MULTIHOLDER_INDICATOR
FROM ADM_MULTITITULARES;
```

El error que me da es pq el from no se encontraba donde se esperaba. No sé si alguien podria echarme un cable, no lo llego a tener claro del todo. Es en Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Te falta un paréntesis al final de tu subconsulta.

Answer (score 1):

Pues es un error de sintaxis:

```sql
SELECT *,
 CASE WHEN val_date = max(val_date) 
      THEN 'Y'
      ELSE 'N'
 END AS MULTIHOLDER_INDICATOR
FROM ADM_MULTITITULARES;
```

Comment: Resulta que ese no era el problema ya lo he solventado y era una cosa mas compleja pq tenia que unir con otras tablas, pero ya lo he podido resolver.
Muchas gracias igualmente!

Comment: @victordiaz podrías colocar la resolución para poder observarla y que la comunidad sepa que existe una resolución para este tema.